# Excel VBA to copy rows if cell empty and delete if value deleted

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code to copy the row (A to G) if column D is not blank to a different worksheet in the workbook. It works just fine. However, I need it to delete the row from the spreadsheet that it is copied to if the value is removed from the column.

So the user will put in a value in a cell in column D. That row is copied to a different spreadsheet. But if they change their mind and delete that value, I need the row removed from the other spreadsheet.

Here's what I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sIn As Worksheet, sOut As Worksheet, rIn As Range, rOut As Range
    Dim inputdata() As Variant
    Dim tmpArr(1 To 7) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, outcount As Long

   Set sIn = Sheets("Supply Request")
   Set sOut = Sheets("Order")
   Set rIn = sIn.UsedRange
   Set rOut = sOut.Range("A5:G5")

   inputdata = rIn.Value
   outcount = 0

   For i = 1 To UBound(inputdata, 1)
       If inputdata(i, 4) <> "" Then
           outcount = outcount + 1
           tmpArr(1) = inputdata(i, 1)
           tmpArr(2) = inputdata(i, 2)
           tmpArr(3) = inputdata(i, 3)
           tmpArr(4) = inputdata(i, 4)
           tmpArr(5) = inputdata(i, 5)
           tmpArr(6) = inputdata(i, 6)
           tmpArr(7) = inputdata(i, 7)
           rOut.Offset(outcount - 1, 0).Value = tmpArr
           Erase tmpArr
       End If
   Next i
   Erase inputdata
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is your code not working? What errors are you encountering? Also your question would be much enhanced if you provided some sample data to test against. Regards

Comment: I don't know, but you have problem because this line "columns B, I, and N on Output sheet row by row." is not a comment?

Comment: I dont see a simple solution other than, in the same `Worksheet_Change` handler,  checking for empty cells in column `D`, one by one, then finding the matching row in the `Order` sheet to remove it. Besides, if there are duplicates, it will be even more difficult.

Comment: By the way, why are copying everything all over again whenever anything changes in the `Supply Request` worksheet?

Comment: Sorry. It was another code I modified to work with my spreadsheet and forgot to change the comments to match.

Comment: nbayly - My code is working just fine. I'm looking to modify it.

A.S.H. The code is copying rows from "Supply Request" if column D is not empty into "Order". I have another script to email the Order spreadsheet only and not the whole workbook. It's a supply order request form that's 14 pages. It's so that the person who is going to order the actual supply won't have to shift through 14 pages.

Comment: What you'll want is a `Worksheet Change` event, in the destination sheet, like @A.S.H suggested. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Kaylee, Is there in the data any key column that is unique to the row, such as an Identifier? This would be very helpful to retrieve the row to delete when the user deletes any cell in column D.

Comment: Column A contains item number and each one is unique.

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing: